# How to get file path using getContentResolver().query() in onActivityResult() after choosing a file via File Browser

Tags: java, android

Normally, for a picture, I get it by using followed code inside `onActivityResult()` and it works fine:

```
Uri photoUri = data.getData();
Cursor cursor = null;
String filePath = "";

// Use are cursor to get the filePath
try {
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
    LogHelper.LogError("DialogUpsertPictureFragment error.", ex);
} finally {
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.close();
}
```

However, when I tried something similar for File, somehow, the `cursor` always returns `null`. The difference is at the `projection` parameter of `getContentResolver().query()`. I changed the `projection` from `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` to `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA`. Here is what I have tried:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
Cursor cursor = null;
String filePath = "";
try {
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA};
    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
    LogHelper.LogError("DialogUpsertAttachmentFragment error.", ex);
} finally {
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.close();
}
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: normally we are not trying to get the path ... normally we are getting content from the uri

Comment: google for: how consume content uri

Comment: @Selvin But we can also get the path to the file on disk. can't we? So, eventually, I can manage it through `File mediaFile = new File(filePath);` ?

Comment: if you really, really, really, really need a path (which i doubt) then create new file and copy content

Comment: what you need is `InputStream`, not `File` - see `ContentResolver` docs on how to do that

Answer (score 1):

If you have already defined [file provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) and [read storage permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) in the manifest file, then this line of code should give you the file path:

```
String filePath = uri.getPath();
```